# How can I find a drupal installation?

Tags: drupal

Related to the highly critical security issue [PSA-2018-001](https://www.drupal.org/psa-2018-001) I would like to find out who of our customers are using Drupal based on accessing the fileshare they are using.
Something like using a specific "find" statement to locate Drupal 7 and 8 installations would be handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
find / -name "bootstrap.inc" -exec grep "VERSION" {} \;
```

According to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/181786) this should be the file containing the version of Drupal. This command will search for every `bootstrap.inc` file in `/` and search for the line containing the keyword `VERSION`

By the way, I think your question belong to the Drupal StackExchange.

Comment: Based on your answer I started looking for other drupal version specific files and I found this very helpful: https://github.com/droope/droopescan/blob/master/dscan/plugins/drupal/versions.xml
By calculating a md5sum on certain files one can guess which version is installed.